# How can you get the current table in MS Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wish to be able to run a VBA module which manipulates the table that I'm currently in (i.e., the cursor is somewhere within that table). The VBA code will perform an identical operation on each table that you're in when you run it.

So, for example, let's say I have a module which needed to bold the top row of each table (the headings). It would need to locate the table object (called `whatever`) that you're currently in so that it could manipulate `whatever.rows(0)`.

How can I get the table object from the cursor position? I also need to detect if I'm *not* in a table and do nothing (or raise an error dialog).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The VBA subroutine at the bottom of this answer shows how to do this.

It uses the current selection, collapsing it to the starting point first so as to not have to worry about multi-segment selections:

```
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
```

It then checks that selection to ensure it's inside a table

```
    If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        MsgBox "Can only run this within a table"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The table is then accessible by referring to `Selection.Tables(1)`.

---

The code below was a simple proof of concept which simply toggled each of the starting cells in each row of the table to either insert or delete a vertical bar marker.

```
Sub VertBar()
    ' Collapse the range to start so as to not have to deal with '
    ' multi-segment ranges. Then check to make sure cursor is '
    ' within a table. '
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        MsgBox "Can only run this within a table"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Process every row in the current table. '
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    For row = 1 To Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
        ' Get the range for the leftmost cell. '
        Set rng = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(row).Cells(1).Range

        ' For each, toggle text in leftmost cell. '
        If Left(rng.Text, 2) = "| " Then
            ' Change range to first two characters and delete them. '
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            rng.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
            rng.Delete
        Else
            ' Just insert the vertical bar. '
            rng.InsertBefore ("| ")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11):

I realise this is a rather old question, but I stumbled across some code that may help the next person who is facing a similar problem.

```
ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.count
```

This will return the index of the table the cursor is in. Which can then be used to make changes or retrieve information:

```
dim numberOfColumnsInCurrentTable as Integer
dim currentTableIndex as Integer

currentTableIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.count
numberOfColumns = ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Columns.count
```

Obviously checks should be added to ensure the cursor is within a table.

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I needed @enifeder: ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.count