# Can we access a word table by its name and not index using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to access tables from a word document and I got a method that uses its index. But for my project, it arises confusion so I want to use their names as we can do in excel using this.

`Set tbl = oExcelWorksheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range`

But in word to access a table I only found this command

`Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables("1")`

Is there any other command in word VBA through which I can use the table name to access the table and not the index.

Comment: Tables in Word do not have names.

Comment: @Timothy is right but there is a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Timothy correctly pointed out in the comments, tables in word don't have names.

One way around is to bookmark the first cell (or any other cell) of each table with the name you want to give the table

[image]

Then you can use this bookmark to locate your table. For example you can use this function (I used suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226721/how-can-you-get-the-current-table-in-ms-word-vba)) [**Please see Edit1 below**]

```vb
Function GetTable(sTableName As String) As Table
    Dim sCell_1_Range As Range
    
    With ThisDocument
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sCell_1_Range = .Bookmarks(sTableName).Range
        If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Function ' table not found
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Set GetTable = .Tables(.Range(0, sCell_1_Range.End).Tables.Count)
    End With
End Function
```

and use it like this

```
Sub TestTableWithName()
    Dim myTable As Table
    Set myTable = GetTable("SecondTable")
    If Not myTable Is Nothing Then
        myTable.Range.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit1**

@freeflow suggested a much better implementation of the function

```
Function GetTable(sTableName As String) As Table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetTable = ThisDocument.Bookmarks(sTableName).Range.Tables(1)
End Function
```

Which means - depending on your coding style - you might not even need to use a function. Just remember to use `On Error GoTo 0` if you use it directly

Comment: Your function can be simplified to two lines - On Error Resume Next, Set GetTable = ThisDocument.Bookmarks(sTableRange).Range.Tables(1)

Comment: @freeflow Much better, amazing. Didn't think of that. Many thanks. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

what I normally do is give unique title to the table in table properties of the table.
[image]

Then use a custom function.

```
Sub getTableByTitle()
Dim doc As Document
Dim tbl As Table

Set tbl = getTable("Tb1")

End Sub


Public Function getTable(s As String) As Table
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
If tbl.Title = s Then
   Set getTable = tbl
   Exit Function
End If
Next
End Function
```