# Edit tables in the footer of word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

i need to make a program to edit some tables in the footer of a word document. I read something about tables in word : [Can we access a word table by it's name and not index using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463443/can-we-access-a-word-table-by-its-name-and-not-index-using-vba)

But my problem is i have several tables in my footer, and i cant add bookmark because it depends on how many sheets will have my .docx

Here what is look like my footer :
[image]

Do you have any idea how can i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why does "it depends on how many sheets will have my .docx"? A document with 1000 pages may only have a single footer.

Comment: Yes but the bookmark is only for the footer i choose in a particular page

Comment: We don't understand what you mean by "on how many sheets will have my .docx"

Comment: Word doesn't have a "page" object. The footer is a child object of the section. If the document only has one section, it only has one footer containing three tables. So you can easily refer to the tables by index, you don't need to use bookmarks. If you do use bookmarks, they will only exist once, because the document only has a single footer.

Comment: You would do better to construct a template that contains the standard elements you need, such as headers and footers. If you use DocVariable or DocProperty fields to display data in the footer you don't need to access the footer at all. Just update the value of the property or [document variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.variables) then update the fields.

Comment: @macropod i didnt even begin to write code, just asking for advices.

Comment: Look into the StyleRef field. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF Pages do not have footers, only sections. Each section has three, which may or may not be displayed. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings Word does not think in terms of pages. https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html

Comment: @Charles Kenyon, thanks a lot for this, i didnt know about that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Timothy Rylatt, it's gonna be help me a lot !

> You would do better to construct a template that contains the standard elements you need, such as headers and footers. If you use DocVariable or DocProperty fields to display data in the footer you don't need to access the footer at all. Just update the value of the property or document variable then update the fields. –